# Ratio of largest eigenvalue to largest singular value

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, singular-values, spectral-radius, spectral-norm

How much larger can the largest singular value of a matrix be, relative to the largest eigenvalue?

Specifically, given some square matrix $A$ with spectral radius greater than $0$, can one derive a general bound $C(A) < \infty$ such that
$$\sigma_1(A) \le C(A) \lvert \lambda_1(A)\rvert$$
where $\lambda_1(A)$ is the largest eigenvalue, and $\sigma_1(A)$ is the largest singular value?
Obviously for this bound to be interesting $C(A)$ must be finite.

For symmetric matrices we can take C(A) to be $1$, but, generally, does there exist some (non-trivial) uniform bound that depends on, say the rank of $A$, or its dimensions, or its determinant, or its maximum entry, or smallest entry, etc.? If so, how would this bound scale? Polynomially, exponentially, etc.?

For simplicity, what about the case where $A$ is just a $2 \times 2$ matrix.

#### Edit:

So I guess, besides the fact the largest eigenvalue is smaller than the largest singular value, there isn't really any meaningful relationship between the magnitude of the largest eigenvalues and that of the largest singular value, for non-symmetric matrices. As pointed out in the comments, the singular values can always be trivially bounded by the square root of the product of the 1-norm and $\infty$-norm ($\sigma_1(A) \leq \sqrt{\lVert A \rVert_1 \lVert A \rVert_\infty}$) but there doesn't seem to exist any meaningful relationship between the largest singular value and the spectral radius.

Comment: I think this question boils down to understanding the largest singular value of a Jordan matrix.

Comment: There exist  matrices with all eigenvalues $0$, but non-zero ( so singular values not all $0$). So no bound.

Comment: Consider an upper triangular matrix with ones on the diagonal and 100000000000...0000 in the top right corner

Comment: @orangeskid good point, but I was interested particularly in the case where the spectral-radius (largest absolute eigenvalue) was greater than $0$

Comment: @user8675309 but in that case, you could say that $C(A)$ depends on the maximum entry of $A$ right?

Comment: I guess the question is whether there exist some general function $C(A)$ that depends on the some properties of the matrix $A$, for which the bound always holds

Comment: @Mido:  Indeed. But all these functions of $A$ vary continuously... so you still get your counterexample.

Comment: you can always somewhat trivially bound the largest singular value by largest component and dimension.  The largest eigenvalue has little to do with it.  A standard exercise prove: $\sigma_1 \leq \sqrt{R\cdot C}$  where $R$ is maximal absolute value row sum of the matrix (L1 norm of rows and take the max) and $C$ is the same but for columns (or equivalently: the same but for $A^T$).